# Terms for traversing time with direction to the past or with direction to the future?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Consider a collection of artworks ordered chronologically. I would like a term which describes moving through the collection from present to past and a term which describes moving through the collection from past to present.

`Traverse` meaning moving back and forth seemed to me an interesting starting point.

`Retrospective` is clearly a related term. However to my mind this means looking with a view to the past from the present. I would like to convey movement towards the past.

`Chronological` is also related.

`Progressive` is a candidate for describing moving from past to present, or perhaps even moving from present to past. Time is often described as progressing. However I'm not keen on the connotation of improvement which progression has. I would also like two opposable terms, one for a direction to the present and one for a direction to the past.

`Retroverse` is a candidate for describing moving from present to past, which I like. It seems to have some precedent. However what I image would be the complementary term, `proverse`, seems not to exist. What do any of you think about this, does `retroverse` seem like a suitable term to you? Can anybody think of a more suitable complement to `retroverse` than `proverse`? I'm considering using these terms despite `proverse` perhaps being made up.

`Retrochronological` perhaps could mean moving from present to past. Does this word exist? It seems a bit unwieldy, I prefer the flavour of `retroverse`. What would the compliment be? Perhaps simply `chronological`? Is there a better compliment to `chronological` than `retrochronological`? Would you consider `retrochronological` / `chronological` to be more proper than `retroverse` / `proverse`? Which pair do you prefer?

Can you imagine any other potential terms?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any reasons for not using 'backwards in time' and 'forwards in time'? These are the normal terms.

Comment: *reverse chronological* and *chronological*.

Comment: @BoldBen I'd like to use the terms in URLs. The simpler the better. Simple single words would be best. Easily understandable words would be best which means `proverse` is perhaps not so suitable. I could simply use `forward` and `backward`, however I feel both directions are forward, one forwards toward the present and the other forward toward the past. `to` and `fro` or `back` and `forth` might be suitable as well.

Comment: @jxh Thanks. I quite like the idea of making a contraction out of those too, as they are for URLs, `/reversechrono/` and `/chrono/`.

Comment: If you just want a URL, you could reverse the word *chronological*, i.e., *lacigolonorhc*. This is mimic'ing the use of [*gnab gib*](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Gnab_Gib) to refer to the [*big crunch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Crunch). But, that might be too obscure and unnecessarily confusing :-)

Comment: @jxh hahaha I imagine that would be even harder to comprehend than `proverse`. The URLs need to be human comprehendible...

Comment: BoldBen's comment has got me thinking about `back` and `forth`. `to-back` and `to-front` have potential. Perhaps even more so `to-past` and `to-present`. I quite like the plainness of `back` and `forth`.

Comment: If you are designing a website, I would use the same URL, and simply allow the information to be browsed in either direction. Perhaps with VCR/DVR like controls (forward and reverse). No words.

Comment: How about **earlier** and **later**. That would be really clear and relative to the current chronological position. If you're looking at a Jackson Pollock a Kandinsky would be earlier and a Grayson Perry would be later.

Answer (score 1):

*Sequential order* may fit nicely for traversing forward through art, as it's natural to order it by time in a sequence. *Linear* may also be a candidate for the same reason.

For the opposite, if you'd like something other than the reverse chronological order, I might suggest *Retroversion*.

Retroversion via [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retroversion)

> the act or process of turning back or regressing

It has the defining "retro" portion which gives it a relevant subtext.